# Keep windows application running when out of focus

Tags: windows

We are trying to figure out how to trick an application in Windows 7 to keep running when it looses focus.

We have an application that imports new assets, textures and models, when they change. However this will only happen if the application is in focus.

Another example would be if you had a game running in a window, and you wanted it to keep running when you click over to something thing else.

This seems to be the default behavior for many applications, they just stop when they loose focus.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Applications (processes, rather) **do** continue to run when they're no-longer the foreground or active application window. What behaviour are you actually seeing?

Comment: It is only "modern" (aka "Windows Store app") processes on Windows 8 or later which are suspended when they are backgrounded.

Comment: Or the application in question was just written to pause when it loses focus.  Developers do crazy stuff sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to just run the app in a Virtual Machine.  Start the VM and configure it to never enter sleep or lock screen modes. Then start the app in the foreground of the VM.   Even if you minimize the VM, the app should continue to behave as if it was running in the foreground.